# Use PhpStorm to automate API testing

Tags: api, testing, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PhpStorm to automate my API testing. I have a response data format like:

```
{"status":"OK","result":{"data":[{"id":2,"name":"store","slug":"store"}, 
{"id":51,"name":"store-1","slug":"store-1"},{"id":76,"name":"store-2","slug":"store-2"}, 
{"id":60,"name":"test-drive","slug":"Test Drive"}, 
{"id":52,"name":"commencal","slug":"Commencal"}]}}
```

From here, I want to read the **name** data to compare for testing API as below

```
 client.test("check_store", function() {
    client.assert(response.body.data.name=== "store", "store not found");  
 });
```

I am not sure about the format of `response.body.data.name`.
Is there anyone help me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem and want to share it with others. After writing the below statement, the problem has been resolved.
    response.body.result.data[0].name

Comment: Thanks for sharing: will be useful for others in similar situation. P.S. You can approve your own answer later -- will add more visibility/weight when somebody else will be looking for similar stuff.